# Efficient way of finding a specific directory based on input parameters?

Tags: python, directory, os.walk, pathname

Given two parameters, `123` and `abc`, I can uniquely identify a directory of the form:

```
\path\to\unique_123\directory_abc
```

**However**, "unique" and "directory" will vary from folder to folder. I would like to create a function such that `func(123, abc)` returns `\path\to\unique_123\directory_abc`.

Is there something more efficient than using `os.walk` to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly you want:

```
import glob

matches = glob.glob('**/*_%s/*_%s' % ('123', 'abc'), recursive=True)
assert len(matches) == 1
print(matches[0])
```

But avoid `recursive` if you don't really need it, it will often be very slow! If you really *do* need it, I would probably shell out to `find(1)` which is better at this sort of thing.

Comment: This is an interesting idea. If '123' is unique it its directory and 'abc' is unique in its directory, does it matter if I use `recursive = True` or not?

Comment: @codycrossley It depends on whether your `/path/to` is constant or not. Also, you could assert uniqueness earlier by doing two separate calls to `glob` ...

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! `/path/to` is constant. I will explore the separate glob calls option! Your input is appreciated!

Comment: I've accepted your answer per your suggestion in the comments. I used two separate calls to `glob`, and that worked very well.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to see what directories are in folder, use:

```
os.listdir("/path/to/folder")
```

Using this, you can get the names of the subfolders.

If you see a folder like `unique_123` already in there, you can strip the digits off the end of the folder name using `rstrip("1234567890") on the string, assuming that the folder name ends in digits and you need to replace them .

Comment: You didn't post enough details in your question for me to answer exactly, but this might help guide you